# Differences between LATE and Heckman Selection

Tags: econometrics, identification, nonparametrics, structural-estimation, reduced-form-estimation

I have heard that a paper by Heckman and Vytlacil demonstrate comparisons between nonparametric Heckman selection (NP Heckit) and the LATE (local average treatment effect) framework. Could someone clarify the differences and similarities between LATE and Heckman selection?

Comment: Could you develop a little about the definition of NP Heckit, or provide a link?

Comment: A link to the paper or a proper reference would also be useful.